# Explanation for Course and Curriculam

Tags: optaplanner

In general, a course, will have multiple subjects and each subject, under that course, will be taken by a particular Lecturer.

Example: 
Business in Finance is the course and it has 4 subjects.

1. Statistics
2. Finance
3. Accounting
4. English

In Course Curriculum opta planner, can we assume that, Curriculam is (Business in Finance) and Courses are statistics, Finance, Accounting and English?

I would like to restrict only one lecturer can assigned to Business in Finance. Example, there two lectures are taking English Course. How to restrict in this case.

Comment: The Curriculum Course use case is a bit different than yours. You will have to adapt the model in nontrivial ways to achieve what you want. This is probably out of scope for a Stack Overflow question, please ask smaller, answerable questions.